# Moodle 3.9.19 http-https redirect problem, how to solve it?

Tags: windows, iis, moodle

I upgraded my moodle from 3.7 to 3.9.19 version. Now web clients can't download any file. I checked what causes an error. On web browser it shows **Mixed Content**

Mixed Content: The site at '' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at '' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See  for more details.

Mixed Content: The site at 'https://mysite/' was loaded over a secure connection, but the file at 'https://mysite/pluginfile.php/26397/mod_resource/content/0/Bug.balans%20forma%201.xls' was redirected through an insecure connection. This file should be served over HTTPS. This download has been blocked. See https://blog.chromium.org/2020/02/protecting-users-from-insecure.html for more details.

After upgrading, all web clients entering to my site with https. But i never installed ssl certificate in my server. Inside the server, site is working as http. Before update it was normal.

Windows Server 2012R. Mariadb 10.6.11. HeidiSQL 11.3.0.6295. PHP Version 7.4.1. Moodle 3.9.19 IIS 8

I tryed to redirect https to http. It was useless

Comment: In iis, you cannot redirect external requests, My suggestion is to add a certificate and use https, which can solve the problem and be more secure.

Comment: i found what caused the problem. Sys admin added my site to subdomain (nginx). Thatswhy in everyone showing https except server